# Sample vcdiff-java client

Tags: diff, vcdiff

I am trying out vcdiff for creating a diff file from source and target files.
Also, will be applying the diff on source file to get the target file.

I have achieved the above use case with xdelta linux command line tool.

But how to achieve the same using vcdiff-java APIs ?
Any hints or directions will be useful to get started.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think basic use case of diff and apply can be handled as follows.
Here, *diff* is generated from *source.txt* and *target.txt*. Then, *diff* is applied on *source.txt* to get *result.txt* which is equal to *target.txt*.

```
Path source = Files.createFile(Paths.get(basePath + "source.txt"));
        Files.write(source, new StringBuilder(
                "First line of the file.\n"
                + "Second line of the file."
                        ).toString().getBytes());

        Path target = Files.createFile(Paths.get(basePath + "target.txt"));
        Files.write(target, "1. First line of the file!".getBytes());

        final ByteArrayOutputStream delta_ = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        VCDiffEncoder<OutputStream> encoder = VCDiffEncoderBuilder.builder()
                .withDictionary(Files.readAllBytes(source))
                .withTargetMatches(false)
                .withChecksum(true)
                .withInterleaving(true)
                .buildSimple();

        encoder.encode(Files.readAllBytes(target), delta_);

        ByteArrayOutputStream result_out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        VCDiffDecoder decoder = VCDiffDecoderBuilder.builder().buildSimple();
        decoder.decode(Files.readAllBytes(source), delta_.toByteArray(), result_out);

        Path result = Files.createFile(Paths.get(basePath + "result.txt"));
        Files.write(result, result_out.toByteArray());
```